# How to set a "title" or "name" for a bitbucket script execution element?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

i am wondering whether or not one can set a title or name for an execution element in a bitbucket pipeline:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - "Configure": ./configure
          - "Build": make
          - "Test": make test
          - "Long Script": |
            make whatever1
            make whatever2
            make whatever3
```

I'd expect the output to be:

- Configure
- Build
- Test
- Long Script

within the titles, and seeing the script only, if I unfolding the execution elements in the UI, just like with github:

[image: github vs bitbucket]

Any ideas? :-)

The only one I found was to put everthing in bash scripts, but then I do not see the executed command, which I still want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any `step` of your pipeline can have its own `name` property, a good example can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/blog/multiple-steps-in-bitbucket-pipelines).

In case you'd like to assign names to individual commands of your step's `script`, I reckon `echo` would be a good option:

```sh
echo "Test" && make test
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Yes, this is something that I also came up with, but I did'nt like it, as the command still spams the folded entry's title. My solution was like this:

`script:`
`  - alias Step='echo'`
`  - |`
`    Step "Build"`
`    make all`
`  - |`
`    Step "Test"`
`    make test`